# How does OpenCV use a XML file to identify objects?

Tags: opencv, neural-network

I'm building an in androidStudio that uses OpenCV to identify an object. The detection is ok, but I don't know how  a simple file XML allow my programm to idetify my object.
Everything that I know is that somehow OpenCV uses a convolucional neural network to do it, so it's necessary that I do the training of the CNN do adjust the internal parameter, but what   does the XML exactly??? How to works this magic thing??

Comment: Please add details, like what XML you are talking about, and what detection algorithm is used. There are no general answers without these details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure if this is what you mean, but I'm going to make a guess. 
If you use an xml inside openCV to do some sort of detection, you're most likely working with a Haar feature-based cascade classifier or something very similar. You can learn more about it on [this page](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/d28/tutorial_cascade_classifier.html)!

There is also a very good blog post written on which steps openCV takes to make the detection happen: [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/11/10/histogram-oriented-gradients-object-detection/)

Hopefully this can dispel a bit of this magic and clear things up!

In very short, the xml holds a sort of 'pattern' that was learned using machine learning and a lot of examples. Once trained, openCV can search images for the pattern that it found in the xml.